# Getting 'missing module declaration' when using gomobile bind even if the go.mod exists and module is declared

Tags: go, xcframework, gomobile, v2ray

I'm trying to use `gomobile` to compile the `v2ray-core` to a xcframework. The commands are as follows:

```bash
gomobile init
go mod tidy -v
go get -d golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
gomobile bind -v -target=ios -o v2Ray.xcframework -ldflags='-s -w' ./
```

Then I got the errors like:

```bash
write /var/folders/cr/1p6sw8z51sjgf4t6v3k1v12w0000gn/T/gomobile-work-1717835187/ios/src-arm64/go.mod
go: error reading go.mod: missing module declaration. To specify the module path:
    go mod edit -module=example.com/mod
```

**Version Info:**

1. go: 1.22.0 darwin/arm64
2. gomobile: v0.0.0-20240213143359-d1f7d3436075
3. v2ray-core: https://github.com/v2fly/v2ray-core commit 458db39
4. xcode: 15.2

I've checked that there is a `go.mod` file under the root directory and the module declaration exists: `module github.com/v2fly/v2ray-core/v5`. I also checked the temporary `go.mod` file that `gomobile` wrote to, and I found that it was empty. Then I was stuck here.

Could you explain why `gomobile` fails to write to the temporary `go.mod` file? What is this file used for?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was trying to bind all those built-in functions under the root directory as a library. The 'right' thing to do is to create a importable entry for the whole project, as described in https://github.com/v2fly/v2ray-core/issues/1702. However, the reason why `gomobile` was stuck when writing to temporary `go.mod` files is still unknown. (Maybe due to more than one package to share the only module under the root directory?)